# Why does firebase "on" "value" not run the listener function when the reference doesn't exist, but "once" "value" does?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I'm listening to a widget:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`widgets/${widgetId}`);
ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // <-- I never see this if ref doesn't exist!
}
```

If that widget doesn't exist I want to know about it. I'd expect `snapshot.val()` to return `null`. But the problem is the function isn't run at all. So I can't event check for `null`. It just stays silent.

The weird thing is, this fixes it:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref(`widgets/${widgetId}`);
ref.once('value', function(){});
ref.on('value', function(snapshot){
  console.log(snapshot.val()); // <-- Now is null!
}
```

Now the function provided to `on` is run with `snapshot.val()` === `null`. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you please setup a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyp76wj1/18/) like this one that i did and show us your problem?

Comment: Yeah it works in jsFiddle. Damn must something wrong with my project. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to upgrade Firebase to the lastest version (3.0.5 -> 3.2.0)

`npm install --save firebase`