# node.js function not running

Tags: node.js, macos, firebase, terminal

**UPDATE:** This was solved by changing my Firebase database rules:**read** and **write** to **"true"**

When I run my code in terminal I get zero errors, but not all of the code gets executed? 
What's going on? Here's my code, I have dependencies above this code as well but it contains credentials that are private.

```
       console.log('>>>Algolia Search Starting<<<');
//console.log('>>>0<<<'); 

console.log(' ');

var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "...",
        clientEmail: "...",
        privateKey: "..."
    }),
    databaseURL: "..."
});

var firebase = require('firebase');
var config = {
    apiKey: "myFirebaseAPIKey",
    authDomain: "myFirbaseProjectID.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "myFB_URL",
    storageBucket: "myFirebaseStorageBucket"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

//Algolia Initialization 
var algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
var client = algoliasearch('myAlgoliaApplicationID', 'myAlgoliaPrivateAPIKey');
var index = client.initIndex('meal');
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('meal');

// Get all data from Firebase 
rootRef.on('value', initIndex);

// Import Existing Data** 
function initIndex(dataSnapshot) {
    // Array of data to index 
    var objectsToIndex = [];
    // Get all objects 
    var values = dataSnapshot.val();
    // Process each Firebase ojbect 
    console.log('>>>0<<<');
    for (var key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Get current Firebase object 
            console.log('>>>1<<<');
            var firebaseObject = values[key];
            // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key 
            firebaseObject.objectID = key;
            console.log('>>>2<<<');
            // Add object for indexing 
            objectsToIndex.push(firebaseObject);
            console.log('>>>3<<<');
        }
    }
    // Add or update new objects 
    index.saveObjects(objectsToIndex, function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('>>>4<<<');
        console.log('Firebase<>Algolia import done');
    });
}

rootRef.on('value', reindexIndex);

function reindexIndex(dataSnapshot) {
    // Array of objects to index 
    var objectsToIndex = [];
    // Create a temp index 
    var tempIndexName = 'meal_temp';
    var tempIndex = client.initIndex(tempIndexName);
    // Get all objects 
    var values = dataSnapshot.val();
    // Process each Firebase object 
    for (var key in values) {
        if (values.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Get current Firebase object 
            var firebaseObject = values[key];
            // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key 
            firebaseObject.objectID = key;
            // Add object for indexing 
            objectsToIndex.push(firebaseObject);
        }
    }
    // Add or update new objects 
    index.saveObjects(objectsToIndex, function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        // Overwrite main index with temp index 
        client.moveIndex(tempIndexName, 'meal', function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }
            console.log('Firebase<>Algolia reimport done');
        });
    });
}

// Listen for changes to Firebase data 
rootRef.on('child_added', addOrUpdateObject);
rootRef.on('child_changed', addOrUpdateObject);

function addOrUpdateObject(dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Firebase object 
    var firebaseObject = dataSnapshot.val();
    // Specify Algolia's objectID using the Firebase object key 
    firebaseObject.objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
    // Add or update object 
    index.saveObject(firebaseObject, function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Firebase<>Algolia object saved');
    });
}

// Listen for changes to Firebase data 
rootRef.on('child_removed', removeIndex);

function removeIndex(dataSnapshot) {
    // Get Algolia's objectID from the Firebase object key 
    var objectID = dataSnapshot.key;
    // Remove the object from Algolia 
    index.deleteObject(objectID, function(err, content) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log('Firebase<>Algolia object deleted');
    });
}
```

Comment: Would you please format the code?  It would make it much easier to read.

Comment: What code specifically isn't running?

Comment: All of the code under cosole.log(LOG) doesnt get run.

Comment: It's possible that you're registering your on value callbacks after the event has already fired.

Comment: I added the entire function to the code block so you could see.

Comment: Yeah either your on value event has either already fired or is never getting fired.

Comment: Looks right for the most part. Could it have to do with your Auth settings? Like maybe you're not allowed to read out of that database?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774247/firebase-onvalue-not-working

Comment: No, I've checked multiple times

Comment: What version of Firebase are you using? This person needed to update from 3.0.5 to 3.2.0 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416113/why-does-firebase-on-value-not-run-the-listener-function-when-the-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Database rules: read and write were set to null. I changed them to true

Comment: lol, this is what I was talking about. I was going nuts wondering what else it could be

Comment: @CharlieL I literally spent 8 hours trying to figure this out

Comment: This gave some people in the course I'm in some trouble too. It'd be nice if Firebase returned some sort 403 error rather than just doing nothing

Comment: Yeah, I know! All of their error handling in swift is pretty great. I'd expect it to be the same everywhere.